# How to import all sheets from an excel workbook into collections inside a collection in Blueprism?

Tags: collections, blueprism

How to import all sheets from an excel workbook into collections inside a collection in Blueprism?
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is 'MS Excel VBO' as a business object with many 'Action' Stages to :

Create Instance

Open Workbook

Show Workbook (only if you want to see the opened sheet)

Get Sheet as Collection ('Get Sheet as Collection' stage wuld depend on the number of sheets to be imported)

I am not sure if there is a way we could get all the different worksheet data in a single collection.The way I suggested needs separate action stage and collection item to get individual worksheet copied.

Comment: Thank you, I'll keep investigating how to do that. I was thinking in putting double loops for this.